# Having an issue with retrieving the ID from my login application C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql, variables, select, foreign-keys

The button I have checks what is in the two username and password texts boxes in the table username and password columns and if they are both present it signs them in. I can't seem to figure how to set the TeacherID to a variable or let alone find out what it is so I can tell what user has signed in.

(I KNOW MY CODE IS VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION I WILL DEAL WITH IT LATER)

I would very much appreciate any help you could give me!

Here is my attempt to setting the TEACHER ID to an integer called x:

```
private void TeacherLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();


        int x = 0;
        SqlCommand command10 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [TeacherID], [Username], [Password] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ( @x = [TeacherID] AND [Username]='" + this.usernameTlogin.Text + "' AND [Password]= '" + this.passwordTlogin.Text +"');", connect);

        command10.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"x", x ); 
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command10.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;


            }
            if( count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usename and password is correct" + x.ToString());

                this.Hide();
                TeacherDashboardForm TeacherDashboard = new TeacherDashboardForm();
                TeacherDashboard.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("BEEP BOOP ERROR");
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
            }
```

This is my code before I attempted to find what the ID was:

```
 private void TeacherLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();



        SqlCommand command10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Username], [Password] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ([Username]='" + this.usernameTlogin.Text + "' AND [Password]= '" + this.passwordTlogin.Text +"');", connect);

        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command10.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;


            }
            if( count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");

                this.Hide();
                TeacherDashboardForm TeacherDashboard = new TeacherDashboardForm();
                TeacherDashboard.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("BEEP BOOP ERROR");
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
            }
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TeacherDetails] (
[TeacherID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[First Name]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Last Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Title]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Username]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Password]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email Address] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TeacherID] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the query into `"SELECT [TeacherID] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ( [Username]=@username AND [Password]= @password)"`

And then in the code

```
while (reader.Read())
 {
      x = reader.GetInt32(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing I see;

```
WHERE ( @x = [TeacherID]
```

should be

```
WHERE ( [TeacherID] = @x
```

And when you add this parameter value, you need to use `@` inside of string, not a verbatim string literal. Like;

```
command10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x );
```

You said that but I want to say again because it is *really* important. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also strongly suspect you save you passwords as a plain text. **Don't do that!** Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: He always tries to get the user whose ID is 0, but I suppose he wants to get the id from the user whose username and password have been supplied.

Comment: Okay thank you the code I produced hasn't seemed to do what is intended as count always becomes > 1 therefore saying the details are incorrect. The second code I produced works with the signing in part

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: I guess there is no way to have id = 0 with identity or I am wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I was just setting a value for the variable @NikolaDavidovic but I want x to equal the ID of the user who signed in

Comment: @mot375 You don't want to have the id in where part of the query. You want something like this: "SELECT [TeacherID] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ( [Username]='" + this.usernameTlogin.Text + "' AND [Password]= '" + this.passwordTlogin.Text +"');"
Keep in mind what is suggested in the answer, SQL injection problem

Comment: Then use `int x = reader.GetInt32(0);` after you call `reader.Read()`

Comment: Okay thank you very much!!!!!! @NikolaDavidovic how would I set this to a variable? Create an answer to my question if you would like to and I will accept it as the answer

Comment: Oh don't worry you already answered the question ;) Thank you very much! @NikolaDavidovic

Comment: There you have a broad answer. But keep in mind that everything that @SonerGönül told you is totally important and you should implement it according to his suggestions. Note I added the query as you were using parameters, beware of SQL injections or your teachers will have false marks in their log :)